# Создание телеграм бота с поиском по сайту

Tags: поиск, бот, веб-сайт

уважаемые участники!
Есть желание создать телеграм бота с поиском информации на сайте r-hockey.ru
Прошу вашей помощи в определении возможности создания такого бота.
Цель: предоставить доступ через телеграм возможности поиска информации о результатах игр, статистике игроков, календари соревнований. Плюс получение новостей из инстаграма с хоккейных аккаунтов. Аккаунт на сайте r-hockey.ru создан.
Я новичок в вопросе программирования на python. И сейчас хочу понять реально ли реализовать то что я описал выше.
Бот зарегистрирован, токен соответственно получен. Python 3.9.0 установлен, Atom тоже. В остальном я полный ноль. Готов познавать и изучать с вашей помощью.
Благодарю за ответы и поддержку!

Answer (score -1):

Хауди хо в помощь: https://youtu.be/bXxa9IkAPew
Я у него много чего из видосов взял на заметку